# comparing two dataframes and retaining the missing or unequal rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing two dataframes and reporting missing or unequal rows in two dataframes with below code.

```
df1['Dataframe'] = 'df1'
df2['Dataframe'] = 'df2'
df=pd.concat([df1, df2])
diff_df =  df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender','Salary'], keep=False)
```

Sample dataframes

```
   Name | Age| Gender | Salary
0| Naxi | 27 | Male   | 2000.111112
1| Karan| 25 | Male   | 3000.222221
2| Tanya| 27 | Female | 4000.677777


   Name | Age| Gender| Salary
0| Naxi | 27 | Male  | 2000.111113
1| Tanya| 27 | Female| 3000.2222214
2| Karan| 25 | Male  | 4000.67775
```

These are being reported as different as the salary column is not matching. How do I ensure that while matching that column, it only considers first 2 numbers after the decimal and these two dataframes equal out ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `round()` method:

```
df['Salary']=round(df['Salary'],3)
```

Finally:

```
diff_df =  df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Age', 'Gender','Salary'], keep=False)
```

Now if you print `diff_df` you will get your desired output